# Using Knex with own pg connection pool

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, node-postgres

I would like to use knex as a query builder, but my project already handles its own connection pool.

I wish I could to do something like:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')

const client = new Client()
await client.connect()

const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: client,
})
```

Is there any way to provide knex with the pg client object, instead of letting it to manage its own connection pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Unless you write your own custom dialect and override connection fetching functionality. Writing custom dialect is described here https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#i-would-like-to-add-support-for-new-dialect-to-knex-is-it-possible

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid someone would say that.

Comment: Hey there, I am trying to use node-postgres own { Pool } but even with the dialect wiki page I was not able to wrap my mind on how to do that exactly, @allbto did you do it? How?

Comment: @vvo cannot be done unless you want to handle getting connections from pool and releasing them completely manually and then just telling knex to execute the query with the connection you provide. That can be done with `.connection` method.

Answer (score 4):

## Workaround

I think there is a way to do that, but it can be done only with a specific query. To do that you can use the `connection(pool)` method that accept a connection pool instance as argument.

In my case I have required knex without passing a connection argument and then when the connection was established I saved the connection instance in my object. Then when I have to use knex as client I passed the connection instance in the query building.

## Code example

Here a code example:

```
const knex = require('knex')({
   client: 'pg' // postgreSQL or whatever
});

const poolConnection = await new Client().connect(); // or any other method to create your connection here

// when you have to query your db
const results = await knex('users')
                .connection(poolConnection) // here pass the connection
                .where({
                    email: 'test@tester.com'
                })
                .select('id', 'email', 'createdAt')
                .offset(0)
                .limit(1)
                .first();
```

## Use case with [moleculer](https://moleculer.services/)

As an example, I have used that with [moleculer](https://moleculer.services/) that provides a Database Adapter that use already itself a SQL client, so knex would build an additional connection to my db. After I retrieved the connection in my microservice I've used that inside knex in the same way described above.

```
"use strict";
const DbService = require("moleculer-db");
const SQLAdapter = require("moleculer-db-adapter-sequelize");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

// here requiring knex without an actual connection
const knex = require("knex")({
    client: "pg"
});


module.exports = {
    name: "users",
    // implementing moleculer ORM
    mixins: [DbService],
    adapter: new SQLAdapter(process.env.POSTGRECONNECTIONSTRING),
    model: {
        name: "user",
        define: {
            id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            email: Sequelize.STRING,
            password: Sequelize.STRING,
        }
    },
    actions: {
        findByIdRaw: {
            params: {
                id: "number"
            },
            handler(ctx) {
                const { id } = ctx.params;
                // use the connection pool instance
                return knex("users")
                    .connection(this.connection)
                    .where({
                        id
                    })
                    .select("id", "email", "createdAt")
                    .offset(0)
                    .limit(1)
                    .first();
            }
        }
    },
    started() {
        // getting the connection from the adapter
        return this.adapter.db.connectionManager.getConnection()
            .then((connection) => {
                // saving connection
                this.connection = connection;
                return Promise.resolve();
            });
    }
};
```

## Related documentation

- [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/)
- [Knex.js-connection](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-connection)

## Related links

- [Moleculer](https://moleculer.services/)
- [Moleculer ORM](https://moleculer.services/docs/0.13/moleculer-db.html)

Comment: And for transactions, do: `const transaction = require("knex")({client: "pg"}).transaction(undefined, {connection: connection});`